# ajax call returning promis and resolve it by the calling function to its value

Tags: ajax, promise, resolve

By now i read somewhere around 6 pages containing documentations and stackoverflow answers but I don't get the method.

My function is by now after reading all the stuff built like this:

```
async function getFToken(postId){
    const response = await $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
        data:{
        action:'get_f_token', 
        postId: postId,
        },
        success:function(response) {

        }
    });
    return response;
}
```

and in my other function is like this:

```
function getFeedback(postId){
    $(".show_company").hide();
    $(".show_feedback").show();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text json",
        url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
        data:{
        action:'get_feedback', 
        postId: postId,
        },
        success:function(response) {
            var postTitle = '';
            for (i in response) {
                postTitle += "<h1>" + response[i].post_title + "</h1><br/><br/>" + response[i].ID ;
                var test = getFToken(387);
                alert(Promise.resolve(test));
            };
            $("#result").html(postTitle);
        }
    });
}
```

is there any chance, that this is a bigger issue because i call a async in another Ajax call trying to retrieve the value? I'm trying to get the string from the first ajax call and hand it to the second function in the ajax call to attach it to the posts i retrieve from WordPress

The alert is giving me [object Promise] but how do i get the value passed from the php script?

php-scrtipt:

```
//get fToken from specific feedbacks
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_f_token', 'get_f_token' );
function get_f_token() {
    if(isset($_POST['postId'])){
        $postId = $_POST['postId'];
    } 
    $fToken = get_post_meta($postId, 'fToken', true);
    echo $fToken;
    wp_die();
}
```

Comment: Don't use `success` callbacks when working with promises.

Comment: Yes `getFToken` is an `async function` and calling it returns a promise. You need to wait for it like for any other promise.

Comment: Do you really want to call  `getFToken(387)` in a loop?

Comment: @Bergi 1: can i just delete the success callback? 2: how do i wait for it?  3: that is just for testing reasons, afterwards this will be switched with the actual post id from the post handled by the loop

Comment: 1. use `.then()` instead. Or `await`. 2) Same as 1.

Comment: so is the await i built around the response const useless?

Comment: Oh, you're talking about the empty `success` callback in the first snippet. Yeah, you can (should) just remove that. But you should also fix the code in the second snippet to use the ajax promise.

Comment: So do i replace the whole success of the second snipped with await and then post into it what it should do? Actually i just recognized i still don't get it :S

Comment: If i change the code in the second snipped from var test = getFToken(387); to var test = await getFToken(387); it is giving me an error

Comment: And if i change it like that var test = getFToken(387).then(alert(Promise.resolve(test))); i still get only the promise objects

Comment: To use `await`, you will of course need to use `async function getFeedback`. Then you can do either `var test = await getFToken(…); alert(test);` or `getFToken(…).then(test => { alert(test) });`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171338/discussion-between-j-doe-and-bergi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `success` callbacks when you can use `async`/`await`:

```
async function getFToken(postId) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
        data: {
            action: 'get_f_token', 
            postId: postId,
        }
    });
}

async function getFeedback(postId) {
    $(".show_company").hide();
    $(".show_feedback").show();
    const response = await $.ajax({
//                   ^^^^^
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text json",
        url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
        data: {
            action: 'get_feedback', 
            postId: postId,
        }
    });
    let postTitle = '';
    for (const i in response) {
        postTitle += "<h1>" + response[i].post_title + "</h1><br/><br/>" + response[i].ID ;
        const test = await getFToken(387);
//                   ^^^^^
        alert(test); // no Promise.resolve, you don't want to alert a promise
    }
    $("#result").html(postTitle);
}
```

Comment: Any chance of geting multiple variables of different posts? in the example of my question i replaced the function passing variable with a fixed number (387) but now i would like to use response[i].ID for this if i just replace it it only gives me one variable and the second is empty. guess that has to do with the await function?

Comment: No, passing `response[i].ID` should work just fine. Are you sure that the PHP api works? Btw, if `response` is an array, [Don't use a `for…in` enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572)!

Comment: you're right, thank you so much. it was the category in the php script which should have been category_name =)